# Generate Table from Sheet to HTML Web App using Google App Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am working on a web app via Google Script where every time I search for a specific text it will generate a table that I linked in Google Sheet in that Web App.

This is what I have so far:

- Google Sheet which has a QUERY function to populate my desired result
- Web App Script where I can insert input and it will be added to the Google Sheet and trigger the Query
- Web App Script where it fetches the table from Google Sheet and displays it on the Web App

The script seems to be working fine because when I enter the text in the Input field it is being added but it does not automatically show in the Web App the QUERY Table result and seems that I have to hit refresh first before it will show the new QUERY Table in Google Sheet.

Here is my HTML JS Script:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div>
  
  <label for="fname">First Name</label><input type="text" id="fname">
  <button id="btn">Search</button>
  
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div>
  <table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>First Name<th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="FnameData">
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  
 <script>
 
     document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",SearchFunction);
     
     
     
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).searchFunc();
     
     });
     
     
     
     function SearchFunction() {
     
         var sdata = document.getElementById("fname").value;
         google.script.run.sQuery(sdata);
     
      }
   
     
     function generateTable(tableDataArray) {
  
         var tbody = document.getElementById("FnameData");
     
         tableDataArray.forEach(function(r){
     
         var row = document.createElement("tr");
         var col1 = document.createElement("td");
     
         col1.textContent = r[0];
         row.appendChild(col1);
         tbody.appendChild(row);
     
         }) 
       }
       
  
  </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are my JavaScript Scripts in Google App Scripts:

Generating the Table

```
function searchFunc() {
 
  var url = "";
  var SSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  
  var WSheet = SSheet.getSheetByName("Test");
  var Data = WSheet.getRange(5, 2, WSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  //Logger.log(Data);
  return Data;
  
}
```

Adding Data on the QUERY Table

```
function sQuery(EData) {
 
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("");
  var WS = SS.getSheetByName("Test");
  
  var WData = WS.getRange(1, 1).setValue(EData);
   

}
```

Comment: I just posted an answer. If you need something more specific, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts or post more specific questions (try to identify the underliying problems and fix them one by one).

Comment: Thank you, yes that gave me an idea and your comment was really appreciated I think I need to focus on changing my logic more when I do this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client-side code (the Google Apps Script HTMLOutput object, HTML/CSS/JavaScript) you could  use the JavaScript global object [Promise](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to handle the sequence of asynchronous tasks (like calling `google.script.run`)

Another option might be to change the logic of your web app so instead calling different functions call only one that call the server-side function in the sequence that you need.

NOTE: On the server side code you might need to add `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.